Table talk in Euchre
In Euchre, is telling your partner you have the trick before they play considered table talk?

These are two different questions.

By letting them know you have the trick based on what cards have already been played?

Yes, by letting your partner know you have the trick by the cards that have been played

How exactly is that table talk by talking about cards that have been publicly played and stating the state of the trick which is also publicly known?

Because you must do it in all such cases, or the fact you are doing it specifically in that case implies information about game state that is not public. @JoeW

@Nij Unless the partners are somehow sharing knowledge about what is in their hands, I am not sure how a statement about you taking the tricks is sharing knowledge.

Whenever you specifically identify that you are winning the trick, as opposed to when you don't, it is an indication that  partner does not need to, therefore they should discard dross and allow you to lead next, or further, that you specifically have a plan for leading at least the next trick and partner should not overplay or trump. This is absolutely tabletalk.

I assume "before partner leads to the next trick", the equivalent of "I'm on lead".  Because "partner, you can see this one's mine, don't overruff me", never mind "partner, I've got this one (but I haven't played yet), don't waste a card", which are clearly wrong.  I don't know the answer without looking at the rules, should there be an official set of rules.

Strictly speaking, it's table talk, but if your partner needs help identifying the winner, then it's a learning game. Therefore, some table talk should be acceptable.

Yes, this is absolutely tabletalk.
Whenever you specifically identify that you are winning the trick, and as opposed to when you don't, it is an indication that partner does not need to, therefore they should discard dross and allow you to lead next.
Further, the statement itself along with the particular timing and tonality of the statement can further indicate that you specifically have a plan for leading at least the next trick and partner should not overplay or trump.
If it is likely that they would not have realised this fact themselves, such as when they are learning a new game or aren't used to how euchre in particular works, it is also quite likely that they're new and you're teaching them how to play, so it is best pointed out explicitly to help them learn.
If they should be expected to recognise the game state on their own, you should just expect them to play a card based on the public game state plus their own hand plus the reasonable inferences from the combination. You should not be making comments at all; if they make a mistake,  that's on you as a team, because otherwise you should just play computers and not with humans.
